# Can't find issue with "Too many arguments for format"

Tags: c, printf

I am having trouble with my sprintf statement. I see 6 argument formats and 6 supplied arguments, but I am getting the following error:

> jsonServer.c:450:4: error: unknown conversion type character ‘}’ in
>   format [-Werror=format=]
>   sprintf(message, "{\"num_clients\": %d,\"num_requests\":
>   %d,\"errors\": %d,\"uptime\": %u,\"cpu_time\": %lu,\"memory_used\":
>   %l}", (numConnections+1), numRequests, numErrors, uptime, cpuTime,
>   memUsed);
>   jsonServer.c:450:4: error: too many arguments for format
>   [-Werror=format-extra-args]

```
char *buildStatus()
{
   struct rusage *usage = malloc(sizeof(struct rusage));
   int usageRet = getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, usage);
   if (usageRet == -1)
   {
      perror("RUSAGE fail");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }
   long unsigned cpuTime = (usage->ru_utime).tv_sec + (usage->ru_stime).tv_sec;
   long memUsed = get_memory_usage_linux();
   unsigned int uptime = 0;

   char *message = malloc(1000);
   sprintf(message, "{\"num_clients\": %d,\"num_requests\": %d,\"errors\": %d,\"uptime\": %u,\"cpu_time\": %lu,\"memory_used\": %l}", (numConnections+1), numRequests, numErrors, uptime, cpuTime, memUsed);
   free(usage);
   return message;
}
```

I think there is some sneaky escape character issue, but after sticking backslashes everywhere, I can't seem to fix it.

Comment: On the end the `%l}` is not a valid conversion. You probably meant to `%ld}`. This you have 4 conversion specifiers (ie. `%d` or similar) in printf and 6 arguments. Thus you have one argument more then conversion specifiers.

Comment: Invalid conversion specifier, behaviour is undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

all you have to do is correct the `%l`(there is not such a specifier), you probably should have used `%ld`.

```
char *buildStatus()
{
   struct rusage *usage = malloc(sizeof(struct rusage));
   int usageRet = getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, usage);
   if (usageRet == -1)
   {
      perror("RUSAGE fail");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }
   long unsigned cpuTime = (usage->ru_utime).tv_sec + (usage->ru_stime).tv_sec;
   long memUsed = get_memory_usage_linux();
   unsigned int uptime = 0;

   char *message = malloc(1000);
   sprintf(message, "{\"num_clients\": %d,\"num_requests\": %d,\"errors\": %d,\"uptime\": %u,\"cpu_time\": %lu,\"memory_used\": %ld}", (numConnections+1), numRequests, numErrors, uptime, cpuTime, memUsed);
   free(usage);
   return message;
}
```

hope that helps.

Comment: all OP really had to do was read the first error message